# Hosting nancy with asp.net on IIS 6 - failed - wrong configuration

Tags: nancy

I tried some stuff to host a little nancy test api under IIS 6:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-asp.net

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

But it dont work. Here are my steps:

1. Create Empty Nancy Web Application
2. Add Reference with nuget - Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet Version 0.15.1

   - new Web.config is modifyed automatically
   - as described in the wiki
3. Add new class in solution root - HelloModule.cs

   - insert test code "HelloWorld"
4. Publish the web site local

   - on Windows 2003
   - with a virtual Directory in the IIS manager

Browsing the url 'localhost/nancyTest' brings an HTTP 403 ERROR.

A little ASP.NET WebApplication runs with the same configuration.

The nancyTest application does not have a start site like default.aspx. I want to get the request response from .../nancyTest/ coded as:

```
public class HelloModule : NancyModule
{
    public HelloModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters => "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Perhaps the call .../nancyTest/ is not a GET Request? Are there other things to go in more detail?

Comment: It Works with _Wildcard application maps(...)_ under _Application Configuration_ . I added the extension for aspnet_isapi.dll in this section. Sadly that isn't directly described in the wiki (just for PUT/DELETE Requests)

Comment: Get["/"] is nancy Get Request. Go to ISS and try run this site as administrator. It can be some kind of 'security issue'. Give site deafult user in ISS as serwer admin (user login and password). It helped me in one solution in asp.net web forms when I had wcf in solution, that connects to another page.

Answer (score 0):

I know not so many people user IIS6 nowadays, but there is the following solution, i wish it can help some people that still use this old one,

1. Config aspnet_isapi to handle a new ext files and like , `.start`
2. Set default page for this application is `index.start`
3. In nancy module add the redirect method, like the follwing:

```js
Get["index.start"] = _ => {
    return Response.AsRedirect("~/", Nancy.Responses.RedirectResponse.RedirectType.Permanent);
};
```

wish it helps